# A pythonic approach to extracting data from array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a more pythonic way of extracting data from this txt file? 
It seems cumbersome to declare global variables beforehand and iterate using range rather than python's for i in i approach.

```
data1 = np.loadtxt("testProfil5.txt",float,delimiter=None)
x,y = [],[]
for i in range(np.size(data1)/2):
    x.append(data1[i][0])
    y.append(data1[i][1])

plt.plot(x,y)
```

Although this works, I would appreciate a more pythonic approach. I know there is pandas and numpy arrays...

Comment: `np.loadtxt` returns a Numpy array. You can just pass the array to `pyplot`.

Comment: my first thought, but that doesn't seem to work properly, the answer below works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using Python lists whenever possible when you have NumPy arrays containing your data.  In your case:

```
x = data1[:,0]
y = data1[:,1]
```

Then you can plot the data directly, with no copying.

P.S.: if you do need `np.size(data1)/2` someday, you can simply say `len(data1)`, because all you're really doing is getting the number of rows (first dimension).

Comment: thank you, albeit down voted it really helps to get to grips with some functionality, highly appreciate the answer and the P.S comment